# Samba transfer speed from PC -> Server is stuck at 80 MB/s

Tags: linux, networking, debian, samba

I have Samba 4.9.5-Debian installed on my server. The server runs Debian 10.

When I transfer a single large file from my Windows PC to the server, I am getting consistent 80 MB/s speeds no matter what I do. I've tried adding a few parameters to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, from posts on superuser, but nothing worked (even after restarting smbd service or running reload-config).

If I take a speed test on my Debian server, I get a consistent 950 Mbps on both download and upload, which should give me a theoretical maximum transfer speed of ~120 MB/s. 40 less than expected.

I get the same speed on my Windows PC.

Any clues?

EDIT: Hmm, I just tried making a speed test using iperf3 and it seems like my connection speed is limited to about 660 MB/s, which would explain the ~80 MB/s I am getting. Very weird.

Comment: How about when you transfer a file from the Debian machine to the Windows PC? Is it faster? It could be the Windows PC has a limited read speed from whatever you're copying from.

Comment: @SamForbis I edited my post. I noticed it's most likely not a Samba issue at all

Comment: Gotcha. Is this a LAN transfer or is the Debian machine hosted elsewhere?

Comment: @SamForbis Both in my local network. PC -> Router -> Debian machine. I use an ASUS RT-AC3200

Comment: Does your router have any kind of QoS enabled?

Comment: @SamForbis Nope everything is turned off. Hmmm

Comment: If you have a gigabit switch laying around that you could use, I'd recommend attaching the Windows and Debian machines to that to rule out the router.

Comment: @SamForbis I have a couple of 24 port managed gigabit switches, but they're quite loud. Could try to set one up as "dumb" just to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104720/discussion-between-sam-forbis-and-mortenmoulder).

Answer (score 1):

Sam Forbis was able to help me with a lot of troubleshooting, but it actually ended up being my Windows 10 driver being 1 version behind. I guess they must have fixed something in that latest patch (which was only 10 MB), because now I am able to transfer at full speeds.